# Android App using Eclipse - Creating a button array

Tags: android, arrays, eclipse, button

I'm writing an app that needs 86 small, square buttons in one layout - 6 columns preferably. I want to reference the buttons to show a different image depending on the button pressed. I coded it the hard way using a relative layout> scrollview (in XML), then 86 individual buttons, but it seemed like an amateur solution.

Can someone show me how to code an array of identical buttons with different id's directly within the Java class the right way? (By the way, i have tried hard to find this answer with Google, but when i search variations of this question i always get tutorials about JButtons, which i believe can't be used in an android app).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
public class Test extends Activity{

List<Button> buttonList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonList=new ArrayList<Button>();
    Button doneButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.your_final_button);
    ScrollView view=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.your_scroll_view);
    view.addView(tableLayout(20));//20 rows
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(Button b : buttonList){
                b.getText();//whatever you wanna do
            }

        }
    });

}
private TableLayout tableLayout(int count) {
    TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    tableLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);
    tableLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    int noOfRows = count ;
    for (int i = 0; i < (noOfRows+1); i++) {
        int rowId = 3 * i;
        tableLayout.addView(createOneFullRow(rowId));
    }

    return tableLayout;
}

private TableRow createOneFullRow(int rowId) {
    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
    tableRow.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
    //6 columns
    tableRow.addView(createButton("text1"));
    tableRow.addView(createButton("text2"));
    tableRow.addView(createButton("text3"));
    tableRow.addView(createButton("text4"));
    tableRow.addView(createButton("text5"));
    tableRow.addView(createButton("text6"));

    return tableRow;
}
private View createButton(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Button button = new Button(this);

    button.setText(string);
    buttonList.add(button);

    return button;
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much for your efforts to answer this. I look forward to trying the code. I apologise that i can't vote, i don't have 15 points yet.

Comment: I think you can accept the answer instead of voting it.